# Vuejs: How to write directives similar to v-model, for jquery plugins

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

The v-model directive is limited to `input` event. but i want it to support jquery `change` events too, so that i can use jquery plugins like bootstrap-toggle without having to write separate codes to manipulate those fields.

The main challenge i'm facing is how to update the value bound to the element, on jquery `change` event. I tried triggering `input` event on `change` event is fired, but it didn't work.

Here is what i'm trying to achieve:

HTML:

```
<input id="dayparting_switch" v-observe="options.dayparting" v-model="options.dayparting" :cheked="options.dayparting" data-off="Disabled" data-on="Enabled" data-toggle="toggle" type="checkbox">
```

Custom directive:

```
Vue.directive('observe', {
    bind: function(el, bind, vnode) {
        $(el).is(':checkbox') ? $(el).prop('checked', !!bind.value) : $(el).val(bind.value);
        $(el).change(function() {
            var newVal = $(el).is(':checkbox') ? $(el).prop('checked') : $(el).val();

            // Here comes problem: how to set new value to options.dayparting ? 
            // 1) bind.value = newVal won't trigger any update
            // 2) this.dispatchEvent(new Event('input')) also doesn't work
            // 3) Only quirky way of doing this is to parse bind.expression to get object and keys and then use Vue.set

            var lastDot = bind.expression.lastIndexOf('.');
            var object = bind.expression.substring(0, lastDot);
            var key = bind.expression.substr(lastDot+1);
            Vue.set(eval('vnode.context.' + object), key, newVal);
        });
    }
});
```

The above method actually worked for me, but i think it is not a perfect method. for eg, it won't work for `v-observe="options[option_name]"`

Is there any simple or standard method to achieve this ?

Comment: Do not mix jQuery with VueJS. This is really not good idea. You can do all with VueJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vue 1, it was possible to write two-way binding directives (like v-model), but in Vue 2, you do it with components.

Have a look at the [Wrapper Component Example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html).